# Temperature calculator by cricket chirps program

Tags: python

This program calculates the temperature by the amount of cricket chirps in 13 seconds.  You add 40 to that total and it's the temperature.  If the temperature is less than 55, the program is supposed to return "It is too cold for crickets".

```
chirps = input("How many chirps did you count?")
float(chirps)
def temp(chirps):
    if chirps + 40 >= 55:
         print("By my calculations, it is", temp, "degrees.")
    else:
         print("It is too cold for crickets.")
```

I have tried different ways and its just not doing what I want.  Either there is an unexpected indent, it doesn't register the `>=`, or a million other problems.

Comment: You never call your function `temp`, you just define it. It never runs with your input. You also convert the value of the variable `chirps` to a float and then throw the converted value away by not doing anything with it or assigning it to anything.

Comment: What *specifically* isn’t working?

Answer (score 0):

```
chirps = int(input("How many chirps did you count?"))
if chirps + 40 >= 55:
    print("By my calculations, it is {} degrees.".format(chirps + 40)
else:
    print("It is too cold for crickets")
```

It would be better to use an integer rather than a float. Also, you never defined a variable "temp", which you used in your print statement.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call your function, Also define your function and call it.

```
def temp(chirps):
    if chirps + 40 >= 55:
         chirps += 40
         print("By my calculations, it is", chirps, "degrees.")
    else:
         print("It is too cold for crickets.")

chirps = input("How many chirps did you count?")
temp(int(chirps))
```